# How to turn on logging for AWT

Tags: java, performance, awt, event-dispatch-thread

I have a performance problem that makes mouse events stack up in a strange way. My profiling tool says that the AWT thread is very occupied all the time.
I wonder if there is some smart way (e.g. setting some value in a properties file or something) to make the AWT thread spit out detailed log messages about what it is doing.

Comment: I suspect that you are doing lots of custom processing inside the EDT. Otherwise it is "quite complicated" to get the event thread very busy.

Comment: With the profiler tool in question, can you not analyse the average time spent in particular methods, and therefore see which are saturating the AWT thread in some way?

Comment: I can unfortunately not make my profiling tool show me any details other than that the AWT thread gets extremely busy when I am moving my mouse pointer around. I have recently seen that the number of events dispatched on the AWT thread is not unusually high. Also, this only occurs when running on Linux. On Windows, everything works like a charm. I am running JRE 1.6 update 27.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AspectJ to 'annotate' method calls. However it very likely makes more sense to use a profiler. Or the "the profiler" that comes with your JDK.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know who this log will be informative. I have just tried to look for usage of logger into AWT classes and did not see anything.

But I probably have other idea for you.

Connect to event queue using `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(listener, eventMask)`. Print events to log file. Probably you will see what kind of events take more time.